# Prevent sql server Compact as a subscriber to anonymous merge pull publication

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce, replication, merge-replication

Is there a way to specify as a property to my publication, to say it doesn't need to handle sql compact subscriptions?

Sql server 2008 R2 as the publisher, when I originally created the publication, I set the compatibility to 2005 and up. I unknowingly used a time column in one of the replicated articles, and realized after it is too late that for sql ce, it comes down as nvarchar.

First of all, time datatype is introduced from 2008, so I changed my publication compatibility to 2008. And createad new snapshot, reinitialized subscriptions etc.
Currently all my subscibers are 2008 express. I will never need to handle 2005 subscribers.

Also, I never need to handle 2008 Compact subscribers. since time is not supported only for compact, my theory is, if I can somehow specify that the publication need not allow compact subscribers and regenerate my snapshot and redo subscriptions, that column will finally come down as 'time' instead of nvarchar.

So, is it a possibility?

**EDIT:**

I overlooked the fact that there is no such thing as 'sql server 2008 compact'. I guess my question now is, after I created a pubication with 'subscriber types' as 2005 and up, and later after atleast one subscriber exists(only 2008 express), I change the publication property to 2008 and up, why doesn't any new subscibers get 'time' datatype? Can someone assure that if I totally delete the publication and recreate it from scratch, subscriptions will get the 'time' column fine?

Answer (score 1):

The "New Publication Wizard" has a "Subscriber Types" dialog, on this, select only SQL Server 2008.